# Django REST Framework: How do I clear the ListCreateAPIView POST form after a POST?

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

How do I make it so that this form is cleared after a POST request is sent? Right now, clicking POST refreshes the page and updates the table data but the form data remains.
The code I'm using is from the [official Django REST Framework tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/). Here is what the view for (listing and) creating views looks like:

```py
class SnippetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
        
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

[image]